# Insert linked table from Google Sheets into Google Docs using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to use Google Apps Script to do [insert a linked table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1499/embed-google-spreadsheet-in-google-document?noredirect=1&lq=1) from Google Sheets into a Google Document.

I'm aware that this is easily done manually using **Copy** > **Paste** > **Link to Spreadsheet**.

But is there a way to do this programmatically using Apps Script?

Comment: If you check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602495/how-to-add-a-hyperlink-in-a-google-docs-using-a-google-script), everything related to your question was answered here. I think you need to dig down deeper as well in the documentation of [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values) and [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) to understand everything.

Comment: Hi. I'm just looking at older questions, like yours, that don't have any/limited comments or answers. Did you resolve the "problem", or are you still looking for help?

Comment: I did resolve the problem myself, albeit in a somewhat esoteric way.
I wrote functions that would look for specifically marked fields in the Google Doc like %%table_1%% and replace these fields with tables generated from Google Sheets data. So yes, the problem could be considered solved for now.

Comment: Hey i understand how to create table and fill the data in Google doc. But did you solve the problem of linked copy , i.e when you change value in spreadsheet this table in doc will show refresh button to fetch the fresh data.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is currently not available.
although already raised the issue that you can track and also add your comments to prioritize it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172154009