# Accessing linked Google Sheet cells from Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to develop a Google Document add-on to manage linked Google Spreadsheet tables in a Google Doc.

For example to allow updating of the source Google Sheet cells with changes applied to the linked cells of the Google Doc.

Although I can find the class list, there doesn't seem to the equivalent of an inlineLinkedTable class.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854637/insert-linked-table-from-google-sheets-into-google-docs-using-apps-script) asks the same question but it wasn't answered.

What class should I be looking at or service.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood. You want to update a Sheet based on a table of a Google Doc? Would you mind sharing an example of how it would look like (screenshot of the Sheet and the Doc)?

Comment: Essentially yes, but "a Sheet based on a linked table of a Google Doc".

See user action flow at https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1w9ahIUt4zWvEOf-8J_0KXf4BI_qCMZxNUKleU4361rA/edit

Answer (score 0):

**It's not possible update Docs linked Tables** from the API or Apps Script service.

There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/124793822) asking for this feature to be implemented. You can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates and to give more priority to the request.

Even thought you are using Apps Script in your example, this is also applicable to the DocumentApp service.