# Insert Linked Chart from Google Sheets using AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-docs

I want to establish a **linked** chart within a Google Doc. The chart is already built in a corresponding Google Sheet.

I've found where you extract hyperlinks (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602495/how-to-add-a-hyperlink-in-a-google-docs-using-a-google-script)), but I can't figure out how to grab the corresponding link for the chart.

Most of what I've found searching wants to build the chart within sheets and paste it as an image one time. What I'm wanting to do is create the LINK between the existing chart in my sheet and the chart that the script will insert for me.

If I need to create the chart initially, grab the chart link, and then post that into the Doc, that's fine too.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function embedchart() {

var doc = DocumentApp.openById('file id')
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet file id')

var sheetName = sheet.getSheetByName('SheetName')
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:B5");
var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];

chart = chart.modify()
  .addRange(range)
  .setOption('title', 'Updated!')
  .setOption('animation.duration', 500)
  .setPosition(2,2,0,0)

  doc.getBody().appendImage(image)

}
```

This does a fine job of appending the chart into my Doc initially, but it doesn't create the link effect that would be found by going to Insert > Chart > From Sheets **OR** Chart.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: don't really know about charts but you can get the id by using `charts.getId()`

Comment: Ahh great. Not sure why I didn't think of that before. So I'm able to get the ID now, and have saved it to log. There has to be a way to copy/insert into the Doc with that specific id now too. Thanks!

Comment: your welcome. I really don't know how to insert it into the doc sorry