# Google App Script to create link in Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I'm pulling data from a Google Sheet to create new Google Slides from a template. Everything works fine, but I can't figure out how to make text clickable as a link once I've replaced the template variable with the spreadsheet data.

How do I replace my website variable, company_website, with the website link AND make it clickable?

```
function createSlidesfromSheets() {
  var dataSpreadsheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxlink/edit"; //make sure this includes the '/edit at the end
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(dataSpreadsheetUrl);
  var deck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // this needs to be the name of the sheet/feuille
  var values = sheet.getRange('A2:M20').getValues(); //this is the range of data to create the slides from. 
  //Logger.log(values);
  var slides = deck.getSlides();
  var templateSlideOne = slides[0];
  var templateSlideTwo = slides[1];
  var presLength = slides.length;
  
  values.forEach(function(page){
  if(page[0]){
    
   var company_name = page[0];
   var company_country = page[1];   
   var company_city = page[2];   
   var company_website = page[3];   
   var company_description = page[4];
   

    
   templateSlideOne.duplicate(); //duplicate the first template slide
   templateSlideTwo.duplicate(); //duplicate the second template slide
   slides = deck.getSlides(); //update the slides array for indexes and length
   
   newSlideOne = slides[1]; // declare the copy to update of the first template slide (right after the first template's slide)
   newSlideTwo = slides[3]; // declare the copy to update of the second template slide (right after the second template's slide)
    
   var firstShapes = (newSlideOne.getShapes());
     firstShapes.forEach(function(shape){
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{company-name}}',company_name);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{company-city}}',company_city);       
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{company-country}}',company_country);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{company-website}}',company_website);

// how do I use setLinkUrl() to make the new company_website text a clickable link?
       
    }); 
   var secondShapes = (newSlideTwo.getShapes());
    secondShapes.forEach(function(shape){
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{company-name}}',company_name);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{company-description}}',company_description);       

    }); 
   presLength = slides.length; 
   newSlideOne.move(presLength);
   presLength = slides.length; 
   newSlideTwo.move(presLength); 
  } // end our conditional statement
  }); //close our loop of values

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to give the hyperlink to `shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{company-website}}',company_website)` in your script.

In order to achieve this, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
     firstShapes.forEach(function(shape){
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{company-name}}',company_name);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{company-city}}',company_city);       
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{company-country}}',company_country);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{company-website}}',company_website);

// how do I use setLinkUrl() to make the new company_website text a clickable link?
       
    });
```

#### To:

```
firstShapes.forEach(function(shape){
  var text = shape.getText();
  text.replaceAllText('{{company-name}}',company_name);
  text.replaceAllText('{{company-city}}',company_city);       
  text.replaceAllText('{{company-country}}',company_country);
  var n = text.replaceAllText('{{company-website}}',company_website);
  if (n > 0) text.getTextStyle().setLinkUrl(company_website);
});
```

- In this modification, TextStyle is retrieved from TextRange, and `setLinkUrl` is used. At that time, the returned value from `replaceAllText` is used as the check of replace.

#### References:

- [replaceAllText(findText, replaceText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#replacealltextfindtext,-replacetext)
- [getTextStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getTextStyle())
- [setLinkUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#setlinkurlurl)

### Added: Answer for 2nd question

And about your new question of `Does setLinkUrl(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, url) not work in this context?`, I think that there is no method of `setLinkUrl(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, url)` in Slides service. I thought that this might be the method of Document service. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setlinkurlstartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-url) So this cannot be directly used. If you want to reflect the link to the part of text, please use

#### Sample script:

```
firstShapes.forEach(function(shape){
  var text = shape.getText();
  text.replaceAllText('{{company-name}}',company_name);
  text.replaceAllText('{{company-city}}',company_city);       
  text.replaceAllText('{{company-country}}',company_country);
  var n = text.replaceAllText('{{company-website}}',company_website);
  if (n > 0) text.getRange(startOffset, endOffset).getTextStyle().setLinkUrl(company_website);  // Modified
});
```

- In this case, please set `startOffset, endOffset`.

#### Reference:

- [getRange(startOffset, endOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getrangestartoffset,-endoffset)

Comment: excellent, thank you, Tanaike. Does setLinkUrl(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, url) not work in this context?

Comment: @yobobos Thank you for replying. At first, can I ask you whether my answer could resolve your issue? If that didn't resolve your issue, I have to apologize. And about your new question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?