# Insert hyperlink with variable into google docs using google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, hyperlink

I have a google Form, and the responses populate a response google Sheet, which has a google Script function to generate a google Document using a template.

I am trying to get the address entered in the Form (stored in the response Sheet) to become a hyperlink in the generated Doc.
I have been using the body.replaceText() to replace all the fields I need in the Doc:

```
    body.replaceText("{{Date}}", date);
```

and its working well, but the address field I would like to become a hyperlink.

I have been trying to do it this way:

```
    body.replaceText("{{Location}}", =HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/maps/place/'+location+'"));
```

But that does not become a usable hyperlink, resulting with this in the Doc (please note while it becomes a hyperlink on this page it does not become a hyperlink in Docs):

=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/maps/place/myplacenotyours")

I have also tried:

```
   body.replaceText("{{Location}}", location = HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/maps/place/"+location+));
```

But this throws up syntax errors.

I have this var:

```
     var location = e.values[2];
```

So perhaps it better to use that to create another var as a hypertext?
I am now trying:

```
     var loclink = 'Hyperlink("http://www.google.com/maps/place/'+location+'","'+location+'")';
```

but that doesnt do it either... I'm now starting to think that one can't insert a hyperlink using replace method?

Sorry for the noob question, but I can't figure this out. Can you help me find a solution and put a var into a hypertext link and put that into the Doc as a link?!
Cheers.

Comment: I don't really know about google docs stuff, but i did some research and there is a method called `setLinkUrl`

Comment: I am now trying to set a new variable into a hyperlink, that references the variable pulled from the sheet...

Comment: I dont understand how to use setlinkUrl

Comment: See if this helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602495/how-to-add-a-hyperlink-in-a-google-docs-using-a-google-script

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
function insertLink() {

  var pattern = '{{Location}}';
  var url     = 'https://stackoverflow.com/a/69143679/14265469';
  var text    = 'how to paste a link';

  var doc  = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var next = body.findText(pattern);
  if (!next) return;
  var start = next.getStartOffset();

  body.replaceText(pattern, text);
  body.editAsText().setLinkUrl(start, start+text.length-1, url);

}
```